# How to clear TextFormField's on a form in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a form that contains 3 TextFormFields. I have a "save" button and a "cancel" button. If the user clicks "cancel" I want to clear the TextFormFields. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thanks.

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 15.0, 30.0, 15.0),
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 15),
                  Text(
                    'Display Name',
                    style: _style,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  TextFormField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    initialValue: _displayName,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'please enter your display name';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _displayName = value;
                    },
                    decoration: _textFormFieldDecoration(
                      hintText: 'your display name',
                      padding: 12.0,
                    ),
                  ),
```

...

```
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: kMainColor80,
                    child: Text('Cancel', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _displayName = '';
                        _mobileNumber = '';
                        _emailAddress = '';
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

Comment: Assign a TextEditingController to the TextField and then on the onPressed of Button just use the textEditingController.clear() to clear the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `controller`.

So, your code should be like:

1st, initialize `TextEditingController` variable somewhere inside the top of your class:

```
final myController = TextEditingController();
```

And then put that controller inside each `TextFormField`. (Note: I only see your first `TextFormField` in the code you provided. So, I only put it once. Make sure to put it on each `TexFormField`)

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 15.0, 30.0, 15.0),
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 15),
                  Text(
                    'Display Name',
                    style: _style,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: myController, // PUT HERE
                    autofocus: true,
                    initialValue: _displayName,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'please enter your display name';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _displayName = value;
                    },
                    decoration: _textFormFieldDecoration(
                      hintText: 'your display name',
                      padding: 12.0,
                    ),
                  ),
```

And then, inside the button, call that controller:

```
                 RaisedButton(
                    color: kMainColor80,
                    child: Text('Cancel', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        myController.clear();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

If you want each `TextFormField` to have their own controller, you can create 3 different controllers variable. And thet call each one of them inside you button

Answer (score 3):

you need to add a controller to your TextFormField:

```
TextFormField(
  controller: nameController,
  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
    labelText: 'name',
    icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.user),
  ),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter Name';
    }
    return null;
  },
),
```

on your setState()

```
setState(() {
  nameController.text = "";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to add controller to each text field  `final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();`
2. Pass your controller to the text field `controller: _nameController,`
3. Now you can clear your text form field using `_nameController.clear()`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this very easy. just use a `TextEditingController` like this :

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.display_name_field = new TextEditingController();
}
```

and when you click on cancel btn you can run this :

```
this.display_name_field.clear();
```

I hope I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can clear **all** TextFormField's within your Form.

You already have defined a key for your Form, `key: _formKey,`
The only thing you'll need to do is, inside a `setState(() {})` execute a reset to the form state, as in `_formKey.currentState!.reset();`:

```dart
  void _clearForm() {
    setState(() {
      _formKey.currentState!.reset();
    });
  }
```

This way you don't have to clear each TextFormField as in the previous answers.